# An asyncTask launched from an onPostExecute of another AsyncTask does not execute properly in API 10

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

**SETUP:**

I have a singleton application class that has a method named `fetchUpdates()`. This method is called by an `UpdaterService` (an IntentService) class. `fetchUpdates()` method simply calls DownloadDataAsyncTask which then calls `UpdateDbAsyncTask` during `onPostExecute` if the data were successfully downloaded. Both AsyncTasks reside in the application class (not sure if this is relavant to the problem).

```
public synchronized void fetchUpdates() {
    String[] mURLs = getURLs();
    new DownloadDataAsyncTask().execute(mURLs[0], mURLs[1]);
}
```

DownloadDataAsyncTask class

```
private class DownloadDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject[]> {

    @Override
    protected synchronized JSONObject[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        String urlData = (String) params[0];
        String urlId = (String) params[1];
        JSONObject[] jSON = new JSONObject[] {
                JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(urlData),
                JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(urlId) };
        return mJSON;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject[] result) {
         if (result[0] != null && result[1] != null) {
             new UpdateDbAsyncTask().execute(result[0], result[1]);
         } else {
             displayFailureToast();
         }
    }
}
```

UpdateDbAsyncTask class

```
private class UpdateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, int[]> {

    @Override
    protected synchronized int[] doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "UpdateDbAsyncTask doInBackground BEGIN");
        int[] info = updateDb(params[0], params[1]);
        Log.d(TAG, "UpdateDbAsyncTask doInBackground RETURNING RESULT");
        return info
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(int[] result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "UpdateDbAsyncTask onPostExecute BEGIN");
        if (result[0] > 0) makeNotification(0);
        if (result[1] > 0) makeNotification(1);
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

Everything works fine in API 16, but execution of `UpdateDbAsyncTask` halts after the doInBackground in API 10. The onCancelled(Object) method is not called either.

**LOGCAT OUTPUT**

```
06-22 16:11:51.047: D/dalvikvm(499): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0089
06-22 16:11:51.057: D/dalvikvm(499): VFY: dead code 0x008c-008e in Lcom/daybreak/android/test/MyApplication$UpdateDbAsyncTask;.onPostExecute ([I)V
06-22 16:11:51.087: D/MyApplication(499): UpdateDbAsyncTask doInBackground BEGIN
06-22 16:11:51.187: D/MyApplication(499): UpdateDbAsyncTask doInBackground RETURNING RESULT
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499): Handler{40567510} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler{40567510} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499):    at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:196)
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499):    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:457)
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499):    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:430)
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499):    at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:367)
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499):    at android.os.Message.sendToTarget(Message.java:349)
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:214)
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSet(FutureTask.java:253)
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.set(FutureTask.java:113)
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:311)
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-22 16:11:51.197: W/MessageQueue(499):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-22 16:11:55.717: W/GAV2(499): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), using local store.
```

**FURTHER RESEARCH**

The [threading rules](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for AsyncTask state that:

- The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
- The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
- execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.
- etc...

To my understanding (which is not much, just started programming) the first `UpdateDbAsyncTask` is executed completely in both APIs because it does not violate any of the threading rules. But the second one is either violating one of the threading rules, causing it to halt execution after doInBackground, or it is something else completely beyond my understanding.

I also found someone else with a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898210/asynctask-onpostexecute-is-not-called-on-2-3). And later it was suggested in the question to

> simply using AsyncTask class for API15+ in my code at all times

But I'm not quite sure how to do that either.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

The problem only arises when I call the `UpdaterService` IntentService class (which calls the `fetchUpdates()` method in the Application class) from an Activity. The code I had in my `MainActivity` is below:

```
startService(new Intent(this, UpdaterService.class));
```

However, when I called `fetchUpdates()` directly using the code

```
MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication) getApplication();
myApp.fetchUpdates();
```

from the `MainActivity`, everything is executed perfectly in API 10.

And also note that the `UpdaterService` is also invoked using a `BroadcastReceiver` class which is set be called at regular intervals using a repeating alarm. In this case the AsyncTasks are executed as expected... very strange.

**UPDATE 2**

The answer by [Streets Of Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1198389/streets-of-boston) seems to be the correct answer. But, curiously, the following seems to work as well:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
        serviceIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), UpdaterService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }
});
```

I used the above code to start the `IntentService` from the `MainActivity` instead of `startService(new Intent(this, UpdaterService.class));` and the problem does not seem to persist.

Comment: http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.in/2013/04/the-dark-side-of-asynctask.html

Comment: It works, because you are now calling startService from an Activity and an Activity is a so-called foreground component. The life cycle of the service that you start is now tied to the life cycle of the Activity and as long as the Activity is in the foreground (ie visible), your service won't be killed/destroyed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the execution of code in an IntentService already runs in a background thread. There is no need to use AsyncTask.

I'm not surprised you get this error. I'm surprised that your second AsyncTask gets called at all. When your IntentService finishes calling the fetchUpdates method, your service is done and your process and/or threads could be scheduled to be destroyed/killed. Depending on how aggressive the OS is, this may happen immediately or minutes later. This means that your code gets to be run on a dead thread, and that's what happens.

Solution:
Don't use AsyncTasks from within IntentService. Instead, just call the code from those AsyncTasks in your IntentService directly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple, in the `postExecute` of `DownloadDataAsyncTask`, simple do this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final JSONObject[] result) {
     if (result[0] != null && result[1] != null) {
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 new UpdateDbAsyncTask().execute(result[0], result[1]);
             }
         });
     } else {
         displayFailureToast();
     }
}
```

Comment: Man, you've got me lost there. I'm relative new the programming. Can you elaborate it a bit (about putting the new function in there)? Thanks.

Comment: Btw, both AsyncTasks are in the Application class, and therefore `runOnUiThread` is not available in the AsyncTasks.

Comment: Haha, it's okay if you are new :P, I just edited the answer, I think if you just changed THAT function to what I just put, it should work fine.

Comment: `AsyncTask` has to be in the activity class, however it runs on a separate thread, and when you do `runOnUiThread()` it calls the function in the activity to make the provided code tun on the UI thread.

Comment: These `AsyncTask`s are invoked even when the app is not running (buy an `IntentService`). If I put them in an Activity class, would the `IntentService` be able to call them to get data and update the database.. even when the activity is not running?

Comment: oh.. I do not have experience with `IntentService` however, have you tried just that change and it didn't work? (Just the part I added, nothing else to change)

Answer (score 0):

in **doInBackground()** of **UpdateDbAsyncTask()** thread class write code inside  **rubInUiThread()**