# onPostExecute never called within GCMBaseIntentService

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

I have GCMIntentService in order to implement GCM messaging to my App. The same code in other my Apps project works fine but in this new project, the device is registering correctly, I get regId, etc... in this class I want to register de device token with the user that it's currently log in, for this I call to my webService with Ksoap2 by using AsyncTask.

The method called to webServices works fine but onPostExecute never is called however doInBackground return String value that I use to know if the method works correctly or I get any server error...

After several hours I think that the problem isn't the method, this behaivor occur with any AsyncTask that I execute, like this:

```
    private void registroServidor()
{
    url = getUrl();     
    class preprueba extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
             return "hola";
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
             // set image for ImageView
            String hola = "hola";
            Log.i(hola,hola);
         }
     }
    preprueba pp = new preprueba();
    pp.execute();
}
```

When I called to registroServidor from onRegistered void return "hola" is run in debug view but never execute onPostExecute...

Somebody knows what is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you started your async on main thread?

Comment: you mean that I call to GCMRegistrar.register in the main activity?

Comment: No, debug never enter in onPostExecute however I have a breakpoint on this line (Log.i(hola,hola)). "hola" string doesn't show in LogCat...

Comment: My development device has Android 2.3.6 and when debug on the device fails but when I run on the emulator with Android 4.1 works fine... onPostExecute is run correctly. I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I say in my last comment, the issue is that in Android 2.3 (API 10 or Below) AsyncTask doesn't work correctly when you use within IntentService like GCMBaseIntentService.

This issue is explain in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898210/asynctask-onpostexecute-is-not-called-on-2-3) . For that the solution is using AsyncTask out of IntentService.