# TimerTask and AsyncTask implementation across APIs

Tags: android, android-asynctask, timertask

I found that AsyncTask and TimerTask do not behave the same across different API versions.

Here's my setup:
A TimerTask is set to fire every once a while. There is a service whose method is called when the TimerTask fires. That method instantiates an AsyncTask for some background processing. Note that the AsyncTask does not touch the UI.

All of the above works fine on Android API 16 and 17, but fails on lower level APIs with the standard "Can't create handler... Looper.prepare()" error, such as explained here [Start AsyncTask in TimerTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496744)

I got around this by changing my AsyncTask to a Runnable, and then starting a new thread in the method of the service manually. However, I wonder what has changed in the API since version 16? Is Looper.prepare() actually called in the TimerTask thread now? If so, is there an easy way to implement the same thing in my code so that I can continue to use TimerTask (the Runnable solution is not optimal in many ways, as I might decide to update UI from the AsyncTask later on).

Thanks,

Veljko

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be that you are not creating the first `AsyncTask` in a UI thread, which will affect all AsyncTasks that have been created subsequently. Take a look at this question - [onPostExecute not being called in AsyncTask (Handler runtime exception)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280330/onpostexecute-not-being-called-in-asynctask-handler-runtime-exception)

The work around is to load the AsyncTask from an Application class.

AsyncTask behavior on lower level APIs is also different. The async tasks truly run concurrently in lower APIs, as opposed to running one task at a time in higher level APIs. That might be a contributing factor.

The Async task is only ever necessary if you need to make UI updates. That is what the pre / post operations on the class are for. Using a Runnable is perfectly ok if there are no UI updates. Just make sure the Runnables do not hang around after they are done with their processing.

You can use alarms like @Atrix1987 suggests, but I only every use them when the scheduling time exceeds 15 minutes (which might still hold true for you). I've explained the reason for that in another question - [Scheduling recurring task in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android).

Comment: Thanks Deepak, I followed the suggestions and added 'Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");' in the Application class. Now it behaves the same in every API version. I also agree about the AlarmManager comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an [Alarm Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321443/how-to-start-service-using-alarm-manager-in-android) for scheduling actions and an [Intent Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for completing them. Since you don't have any need to touch the UI it makes things easier.