# Reducing code repetition with recurring code in if-else

Tags: scala, dry

I'm wondering if the following short snippet, which does show repetition can be made more DRY. I seem to be hitting these kind of constructions quite often.

Say I want some computation to be done either synchronous or asynchronous, which is chosen at runtime.

```
for(i <- 1 to reps) {
  Thread.sleep(expDistribution.sample().toInt)
  if (async) {
    Future {
      sqlContext.sql(query).collect()
    }
  } else {
    sqlContext.sql(query).collect()
  }
}
```

It feels clumsy repeating the call to the sqlContext. Is there an idiom for this trivial recurring construct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can "store" your computation in a local `def` and then evaluate it either synchronously or asynchronously

```
def go = sqlContext.sql(query).collect()

if(async) Future(go) else Future.successful(go)
```

Comment: This changes the semantics - wouldn't introducing a `def` be more appropriate refactor than `lazy val`?

Comment: So the expression is evaluated when go is called. This seems so trivial, but C++/Java/PHP/Python do not allow for this kind of thing right? What is this functionality called in Scala? - it's hard to Google for.

Comment: @hbogert These are called ["nested functions"](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/nested-functions.html), and they're crucial to functional programming. They're often used to define auxiliary recursive functions.  C++ supports [something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4324829/857807), but not quite the same, using lambdas. I don't think Java 7 has anything like this, but maybe Java 8 does, I'm not sure.

Comment: @hbogert Python also supports this. You can have a `def` inside another `def`

Comment: Of course. I misunderstood the Scala syntax. I thought more magic was going on as if this was leaning towards macros, but of course it's the same as: `def go () : Unit = { sqlContext.sql(query).collect() }`

Comment: @hbogert Exactly :) All those extra symbols can be omitted here.

Answer (score 1):

You can execture `Future` in your current thread using [MoreExecutors.directExecutor()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html) which is implemented in [guava library](https://github.com/google/guava).

(If you don't wan't to use guava library, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581188/is-there-an-executorservice-that-uses-the-current-thread))

Using this method, you can switch the execution context according to `async` flag.

Here's the sample code.

You can see that setting `async` flag to `false` makes each `Future` executed in order.

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors
import scala.concurrent.{Future,ExecutionContext}
import java.lang.Thread
object Main {
  def main(args:Array[String]){
      val async = false // change this to switch sync/async
      implicit val ec = if(async){
        ExecutionContext.Implicits.global // use thread pool
      }else{
        ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(MoreExecutors.directExecutor) // directy execute in current thread
      }

      println(Thread.currentThread.getId)

      Future{
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println(Thread.currentThread.getId)
      }
      Future{
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        println(Thread.currentThread.getId)
      }
      Thread.sleep(4000) // if you are doing asynchronously, you need this.
  }
}
```

Comment: I should've stated that the Future was not the main subject of the code snippet and question. Still, a welcome answer.