# Writing a threaddable wrapper for any function of a class?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite

In Java, I have a class that has many SQLite CRUD functions, all belonging to the same class, `SQLiteCrudHelper`.

Is the only way to make all these functions run outside the UI thread is to write a wrapper function for each CRUD function, something that starts a new thread, runs the CRUD function, and then returns a callback so you can implement what happens after it's done?

Or is there a way to make a generic threaded/callback function that will take *any* function you give it and treat it this way?

Comment: why not write your own common wrapper, like `runOnNewThread(Runnable task, Runnable callback)`

Comment: @JiangYD That's what I am asking, I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: java doesn't have a mean that would allow you to take *any* function.

So, pre-java 8, you would normally pass some instance of [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) or using ExecutorService to pass [Callables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).

With Java8, you can have a look into [functional interfaces](http://www.studytrails.com/java/java8/Java8_Lambdas_FunctionalProgramming.jsp) together with [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Long story short. You can just create code that takes some "void*" pointer as in the good bad days of C; but you have several options on how to get closer to that.

Finally: my "personal" choice would be to look into ExecutorServices instead of using "bare metal threads" (or thread pools); as those can be easily replaced with a ["same thread executor service"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581188/is-there-an-executorservice-that-uses-the-current-thread) which makes it very easy to turn your multi-threaded code back to "single-threaded" for unit testing.

Comment: That is why I pointed to functional interfaces: It might be reasonable to use BiFunction for example; and allow for code that takes that interface, refined with some of your own interfaces.

Comment: I am working in pre-Java 8 so I don't think I can use any of that, but I'll accept the answer anyway and just accept that I probably can't do this in Java 7

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Proxy`.

If you have an interface like this:

```
public interface ICL1 {

    public String foo();

    public String bar(String x);
}
```

and a class like this:

```
public class CL1 implements ICL1 {

    @Override
    public String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }

    @Override
    public String bar(String foo) {
        return foo + "bar";
    }

}
```

you can proxy it like this:

```
public class TProxy<T> implements InvocationHandler {

    private final ExecutorService exe = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public final Object object;

    private TProxy(T object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public static <U> U getProxy(Class<U> intf, U target) {
        return (U) Proxy.newProxyInstance(target.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[]{intf}, new TProxy(target));
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object target, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        Future f = exe.submit(() -> method.invoke(object, args));
        return f.get();
    }

}
```

and then you can use the proxy like this:

```
System.out.println(TProxy.getProxy(ICL1.class, new CL1()).foo());
```

Spring does it all the time ;). Enjoy.

Note: this does not take care of the callback. My suggestion would be to annotate your methods with your own home cooked annotation containing some reference to a callback, possibly another `Runnable`, or the name of a method in your interface. You can then use the annotation in the `invoke` method of the Proxy. Make sure your annotation has retention `Runtime`.