# How to write async Scala.js test (e.g. using ScalaTest)?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, asynchronous, scalatest, scala.js

Some of my code is async, and I want to test this code's execution has resulted in correct state. I do not have a reference to a Future or a JS Promise that I could map over – the async code in question lives inside a JS library that I'm using, and it just calls `setTimeout(setSomeState, 0)`, which is why my only recourse is to test the state asynchronously, after a short delay (10 ms).

This is my best attempt:

```
import org.scalatest.{Assertion, AsyncFunSpec, Matchers}    
import scala.concurrent.Promise
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.concurrent.JSExecutionContext

class FooSpec extends AsyncFunSpec with Matchers {

  implicit override def executionContext = JSExecutionContext.queue

  it("async works") {
    val promise = Promise[Assertion]()

    js.timers.setTimeout(10) {
      promise.success {
        println("FOO")
        assert(true)
      }
    }

    promise.future
  }
}
```

This works when the assertion succeeds – with `assert(true)`. However, when the assertion fails (e.g. if you replace it with `assert(false)`), the test suite freezes up. sbt just stops printing anything, and hangs indefinitely, the test suite never completes. In case of such failure `FooSpec:` line does get printed, but not the name of the test (`"async works"`), nor the `"FOO"` string.

If I comment out the `executionContext` line, I get the "Queue is empty while future is not completed, this means you're probably using a wrong ExecutionContext for your task, please double check your Future." error which is explained in detail in one of the links below.

I think these links are relevant to this problem:

https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/910

https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/1039

But I couldn't figure out a solution that would work.

Should I be building the `Future[Assertion]` in a different way, maybe?

I'm not tied to ScalaTest, but judging by the comments in one of the links above it seems that uTest has a similar problem except it tends to ignore the tests instead of stalling the test suite.

I just want to make assertions after a short delay, seems like it should definitely be possible. Any advice on how to accomplish that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was explained to me in [this scala.js gitter thread](https://gitter.im/scala-js/scala-js?at=58b75da7872fc8ce62a2e675), I'm using `Promise.success` incorrectly. That method expects a value to complete the promise with, but `assert(false)` throws an exception, it does not return a value of type `Assertion`.

Since in my code `assert(false)` is evaluated before `Promise.success` is called, the exception is thrown before the promise has a chance to complete. However, the exception is thrown in an synchronous callback to setTimeout, so it is invisible to ScalaTest. ScalaTest is then left waiting for a `promise.future` that never completes (because the underlying promise never completes).

Basically, my code is equivalent to this:

```
val promise = Promise[Assertion]()
js.timers.setTimeout(10) {
  println("FOO")
  val successValue = assert(false) // exception thrown here
  promise.success(successValue) // this line does not get executed
}
promise.future
```

---

Instead, I should have used `Promise.complete` which expects a `Try`. `Try.apply` accepts an argument in pass-by-name mode, meaning that it will be evaluated only after `Try()` is called.

So the working code looks like this:

```
it("async works") {
  val promise = Promise[Assertion]()
  js.timers.setTimeout(10) {
    promise.complete(Try({
      println("FOO")
      assert(true)
    })
  })
  promise.future
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *real* answer here is: you should try to get the "async" part **out** of your unit test setup.

All dealing with waits; sleeps; and so on adds a level of complexity that you do not **want** to have in your unit tests.

As you are not showing the production code you are using I can only make some suggestion how to approach this topic on a general level.

Example: when one builds his threading on top of Java's ExecutorService, you can go for a [same-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581188/is-there-an-executorservice-that-uses-the-current-thread) executor service; and your unit tests are using a single thread; and many things become much easier.

Long story short: consider looking into that "concept" that gives you "async" in your solution; and if there are ways to avoid the "really async" part; but of course without (!) making test-only changes to your production code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how I can apply this to my situation. I'm calling a method `baz` on a JS library that inside of it has this JS code: `setTimeout(setSomeState, 0)`. I need to assert that `setSomeState` has made the required changes to a variable that I have in scope in the test. In my example above I abstract it away as `assert(true)`. But this assertion obviously needs to happen *after* `setSomeState` is run, therefore the assertion has to be async.

Comment: Well, it was more of a generic idea ... when it doesn't apply, I can delete the answer.