# Handler not executing Runnable in Instrumentation Test

Tags: java, android, testing, android-service, android-handler

I have written an Android instrumentation test that calls my service and receives  an answer via an broadcast.

The code to be tested, which speaks to the service, uses handler.

In process of testing my test ^^ I noticed that the handlers are not behaving as expected. So I've written an test to check on this behaviour:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.test.annotation.UiThreadTest;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class HandlerTest {

    private CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

    @Test
    @UiThreadTest
    public void handlerTest() {

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // this code gets not executed
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

        try {
            final boolean finishedWithoutTimeout
                    = countDownLatch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Assert.assertTrue(finishedWithoutTimeout);

        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The handler dosn't execute the runnable code. This is also the problem with my production code.

I got a problem with `Looper.prepare()` that I fixed with the `@UiThreadTest` annotation.

Are there any suggestions regarding my handler problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44651415/549372

Comment: @MartinZeitler Thanks, but this is not really a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you locked your `thread` here:

```
final boolean finishedWithoutTimeout = countDownLatch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And when the `thread` is locked, you can't send a `rannable` with your `handler`. The `Thread` is just locked.
You can solve it by linking your `handler` to another `thread`. Here is a simple solution via `handlerThread`:

```
@Test
@UiThreadTest
public void handlerTest() {
    countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("solution!");
    handlerThread.start();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    };
    Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    try {
        final boolean finishedWithoutTimeout = countDownLatch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Assert.assertTrue(finishedWithoutTimeout);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```