# How to test ScheduledExecutorService exception handling in Junit?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a task which I scheduled to run every 30 mins. I used ScheduledExecutorService to schedule.

I want to test(junit) the exception handling for ScheduledExecutorService such that when ever there is an exception thrown, the thread is not dying because of the exception.

My code :

```
public enum MonitorTask {
    TIMER;
    private final AtomicBoolean isPublishing = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final long          period       = 18000000

    public synchronized boolean initialize() {
        return initialize(period, period);
    }

    /**
     * @return true, if call was successful i.e. Timer task was scheduled
     */
    boolean initialize(long delay, long period) {
        if (isPublishing.get()) {
            log.warn("Already monitoring for new feature data");
            return false;
        }

        //execute on daemon thread
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
                Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(runnable -> {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
                       thread.setDaemon(true);
                       return thread;
                  }
                );

        Runnable runnableTask = () -> {
            try {
                DataPublisher.INSTANCE.update(DateTime.now());
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                log.warn("Failed to check for new Data!", e);
            }
        };    

        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableTask, delay, period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        isPublishing.set(true);
        return true;
    }
}
```

As for now, my unit test check for the functionality:

```
public class MonitorTaskTest {    
    @Test
    public void testInitialize() throws Exception {
        AtomicInteger val = new AtomicInteger(0);
        DataProvider provider = testProvider(val);
        assertEquals(0, val.get());
        // this should update val  every 10 ms ( adds 1 to val )
        Assert.assertTrue(MonitorTask.TIMER.initialize(0, 10));
        assertEquals(0, val.get());
        DataPublisher.INSTANCE.registerForNewData(provider, DateTime.now());
        // wait for 3 updates
        Thread.sleep(10 * 3);
        Assert.assertTrue("Expected val to be >= 3 but is " + val.get(), val.get() >= 3);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        DataPublisher.INSTANCE.clear();
    }

    private static DataProvider testProvider(final AtomicInteger ai) {
        return new DataProvider() {
            private AtomicInteger val = ai;

            @Override public boolean update(DateTime dateTime) throws Exception {
                val.incrementAndGet();
                return true;
            }

            @Override public boolean exists(DateTime dateTime) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override public void close() throws Exception {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are going down the wrong rabbit hole here. Meaning: when you check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor(java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)) for the method you are using, you find:

> Creates a single-threaded executor that can schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically. (Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.)

In other words: you are asking how to test something that is **guaranteed** to work by the Java system library you are using. And in that sense you are wasting your time.

You *might* rather spend time to improve your code to make it easier to test. You see - when your class would *receive* an ExecutorService object (instead of creating one for itself) you could pass in a [same thread executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581188/is-there-an-executorservice-that-uses-the-current-thread) for your unit tests. And all of a sudden, your unit tests can run on *one* thread which makes the whole testing a lot easier - as it allows you to get rid of your **sleep** statements in your tests. (and those sleep statements are **much more** of a problem than chances that threads are not re-started although the system library guarantees you to do so).

Beyond that: your runnable is already written in a way that should *guarantee* that threads running this code *never* die (of course, it is *questionable* to catch *Throwable*). But in order to test that, I guess you *only* need another "test provider" where `update()` throws any kind of exception.

Comment: when it says "single thread terminates" does it include runtime exception as well ? I mean I want to make sure that it doesn't kill the thread when there is a run time exception.

Comment: I enhanced my answer. Hope that helps.