# Forcefully waking up a thread in LockSupport.parkNanos

Tags: java, multithreading

For testing purposes, I want to wake up a thread that is waiting for a scheduling to occur. I have my application in debug mode and identified the thread I want to wake up.

```
Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: not available [native method]  
LockSupport.parkNanos(Object, long) line: 215   
AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) line: 2078  
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() line: 1093  
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() line: 809   
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor).getTask() line: 1067    
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor).runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1127 
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 617   
Thread.run() line: 745
```

Is it possible to issue anything in Eclipse's `Display` window from the top of the stack that will pretend the timeout to have past and allow me to debug code that will be executed on callback?

Of course I know what I am doing and I have no responsibility to take, as it is my localhost machine.

Comment. I know I could design my application with a bug huge green test button that can be clicked only by an admin/developer, but I am still asking this for future use

Comment: Just for the record: would it be an option to use a [same thread executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581188/is-there-an-executorservice-that-uses-the-current-thread) instead of entering *unsafe* territory*? So instead of cheating on some thread waiting for something ... find a (test) solution that doesn't require waiting at all?

Comment: No, this is a web application using Spring massively. I have scheduled a callback and want to test it before the deadline occurs

Comment: @GhostCat in fact I am in the process of *making the button I mentioned*