# How do I test cross-thread queue?

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, testing, blockingqueue

> I am not 100% sure that this is SO-adequate question, but I guess it
>   falls under "[a specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)". Tips to make it
>   more SO-friendly are welcome.

**A bit of context**

In DLang there is no default data sharing between threads - instead we use message passing. As safe and clean that approach is, it makes it hard to scale our code horizontaly. Best example is multiple writer - multiple reader problem - it gets quite complicated when using `std.concurrency`.

Quite common way to solve that problem is to use an in-memory queue - writers push to that queue, readers pull from it, each thread runs on its own pace, and Bob's your uncle. So, I've decided to implement Queue for DLang myself.

**The code**

Queue has following API:

```
module javaesque.concurrency;

Queue!T queue(T)(){
    // constructor, out of struct itself for implementation sake
}

struct Queue(T){
    // internals not important for the sake of question

    void push(T val){
    // ...
    }

    T pull(){
    // ...
    }
}
```

And here's a sample app using that:

```
// import whatever's needed, stdio, concurrency, etc

void runnable(Queue!string q){
    try {
        while (true) {
            writeln(to!string(thisTid)~" "~q.pull());
        }
    } catch (OwnerTerminated ot) {
    }
}

void main(string[] args){
    Queue!string queue = queue!string();
    spawn(&runnable, queue);
    spawn(&runnable, queue);
    for (int i = 0; i< 20; ++i){
        queue.push(to!string(i));
    }
    readln();
}
```

**Question**

OK, so how do I test that? While prototyping I just tested it by running that sample app, but now that I've confirmed that the idea itself may work as expected, I want to write some unit tests. But how?

> Please keep in mind that I didn't add `dlang` or related tags to this
>   question. Even though I've supplied snippets in DLang and the
>   background is highly D-related, I am looking for general help on
>   testing this kind of structures, without constraining myself to this
>   language. Obviously, general answer with DLang-specific addition is
>   welcome, but the question itself should be treated as
>   language-agnostic.

Comment: Yep, it's still open, because the only given answer is not satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "generic" approach to testing is two-fold:

- you focus on the public contract of your constructs, and think up testcases that test each aspect of that contract
- you focus on the inner implementation and think of (additional) test cases to get you into specific corner cases

And beyond that: you obviously first test the whole construct in a single threaded manner. You could also look into similar things as a [same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581188/is-there-an-executorservice-that-uses-the-current-thread) service: you setup your environment to *effectively* use one thread only.

That might be sufficient for "most" of your code - then you might be fine with some few "integration" tests that actually test **one** expected end to end scenario (using multiple threads). There you could test for example that your multiple readers receive some expected result in the end.

Finally, from another angle: the *key* to good unit tests is to write code that *can* be unit tested easily. You need to be able actually look at your different units in isolation. But if you would provide that code here, that would rather turn into a codereview request (which wouldnt belong here).