# Waiting for a method execution

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

Suppose, I have a class `SomeClass` with a method `void process()`. The implementation of this method is smth like `new Thread(this::someOtherMethod).start` (need to execute only `someOtherMethod` in a particular thread).

Having written down a unit test for this method:

`SomeClass class= new SomeClass(anObjectToWorkWith);
class.process();
assertEquals(expectedObj, anObjectToWorkWith)`

I have realised, that as the `process` method executes in a particular thread, an `assertEquals` instruction is called before the `process` method is completed.

Therefore, I have a question: is there some way to wait for the `process` method execution, to make `assertEquals` be called necessarily after the `process`.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. Don't propose solutions that use `Thread.sleep` method or solutions that imply making `SomeClass` implement `Runnable` interface, as these solutions don't conform to the tasking.

Comment: if you make class.process() return the Thread t instance the calling thread can call t.join(). That will wait for the subthread to finish.

Comment: @bhspencer the thing is that the SomeClass class implements an interface with a `void process()` method, that is why i am limited with such solutions.

Comment: In that case you could add another method called wait() to the instance of SomeClass. Have the Thread be a member of SomeClass and in wait() call t.join();

Comment: look into using a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html. Wait the main testing thread and call countdown from the spawned threads.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have **hard** to test code here.

When your code under test creates a new thread instance and uses that - then there is simply **no** good way to write reasonable unit tests.

Instead: consider changing your code under test.

For example: instead of using low level threads, turn to an ExecutorService. And then use a [same thread executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581188/is-there-an-executorservice-that-uses-the-current-thread) for your tests. Because that allows you to turn your multi-threaded problem into a single-threaded one. Just by using a different kind of executor.

Comment: This. Test the internally created `Runnable` for being able to create the result it's supposed to without the concurrency, best you can do.