# Intermittent error verifying call to mock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, executorservice

The following class calls a function `MyService::execute` on another thread.

```
public class Foo
{
    @Inject
    private MyService m_service;

    @Inject
    private ExecutorService m_executor;

    public void foo()
    {
        MyRequest myRequest = new MyRequest("bar");

        System.out.println("TP1");

        m_executor.execute( () ->
        {
            System.out.println("TP2");
            m_service.execute(myRequest);
            System.out.println("TP3");
         } );

        System.out.println("TP4");
    }
}
```

I have created some unit tests that check `execute` is called with the correct arguments. `MyService` is mocked.

```
public class FooTests
{
    private final MyService m_myService = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);

    @Test
    public final void foo1()
    {
        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        InjectionBinder injectionBinder = new InjectionBinder(m_myService, executor);

        // some code that calls foo()

        ArgumentCaptor<MyRequest> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyRequest.class);
        Mockito.verify(m_myService, Mockito.times(1)).execute(argument.capture());

        // check arguments
    }

    @Test
    public final void foo2()
    {
        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        InjectionBinder injectionBinder = new InjectionBinder(m_myService, executor);

        // some code that calls foo()

        ArgumentCaptor<MyRequest> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyRequest.class);
        Mockito.verify(m_myService, Mockito.times(1)).execute(argument.capture());

        // check arguments
    }
}
```

The tests run OK on Windows and OSX but `foo2` regularly rails on Linux.

The reason for the failure is that the mock is not called:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.WantedButNotInvoked:
Wanted but not invoked:
myService.execute(<Capturing argument>);
-> at FooTests.foo2(#line number)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

However I do see the print statements to stdout around the call to `m_service.execute` in `Foo`.

I am using JUnit 4.12 and Mockito 2.2.26.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I've figured it out. Sometimes the test runs to completion before `MyService::execute` is scheduled on the other thread.

Adding a short wait in my test after calling `foo` and before verifying the call to `MyService::execute` fixes the problem.

Comment: Consider using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581188/is-there-an-executorservice-that-uses-the-current-thread

Comment: Remember to shut down ExecutorServices. You leak threads when you don't.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann I did have 'executor.shutdownNow()` at the end of each test while investigating this but it didn't make any difference to the failure.