# Mockito Test case for CompletableFuture.runAsync() which calls void method

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, java-8, mockito

I need help to write mockito test case for below method.

```
public void getCouponAndNotifyAsync(String countryId, String channelId,
        String storeNumber, String clientId, NotificationRequest notificationRequest)
        throws FirestoreException, TurneroServiceException {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> getCouponAndNotify(countryId, channelId,
            storeNumber, clientId, notificationRequest));
}
```

Where getCouponAndNotify() is a void method.

Tried below but its not working

```
@Test
    public void getCouponAndNotifyAsync() throws Exception {
        //doNothing().when(turneroService).getCouponAndNotify(COUNTRYID, CHANNELID, STORENUMBER, CLIENTID, new NotificationRequest("ext_rborse@falabella.cl", "all"));

        CompletableFuture<Void> runAsync = CompletableFuture
                .runAsync(() -> doNothing().when(turneroService).getCouponAndNotify(COUNTRYID, CHANNELID, STORENUMBER, CLIENTID, new NotificationRequest("ext_rborse@falabella.cl", "all")));

        assertTrue(runAsync.isDone());

    }
```

Updated test cases but still not working.

```
@Test
    public void getCouponAndNotifyAsync() throws Exception {
        //doNothing().when(turneroService).getCouponAndNotify(COUNTRYID, CHANNELID, STORENUMBER, CLIENTID, new NotificationRequest("ext_rborse@falabella.cl", "all"));

        CompletableFuture<Void> runAsync = CompletableFuture
                .runAsync(() -> doNothing().when(turneroService).getCouponAndNotify(COUNTRYID, CHANNELID, STORENUMBER, CLIENTID, new NotificationRequest("ext_rborse@falabella.cl", "all")));

        assertTrue(ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        assertTrue(runAsync.isDone());

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a [partial mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others)? You might be better off extending the class in your test and overriding the synchronous method.

Comment: Where are you calling `getCouponAndNotifyAsync()` in your test? I also don't think the mock works like you think it does.

Comment: Can you please explain more on this? getCouponAndNotifyAsync() is getting called in controller class. That test is passed.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you're testing `getCouponAndNotify()` elsewhere so you don't have to worry about it throwing an exception.

What you'll run into is a race condition between `getCouponAndNotifyAsync()` and `getCouponAndNotify()` returning. There are a few solutions for this:

Since you're using the common `ForkJoinPool`, do

```
assertTrue(ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(5, TimeUnit.Seconds));
```

[It waits for the task to finish](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#awaitQuiescence-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).

Alternatively, you could inject an `ExecutorService` and use it as the second parameter to `supplyAsync()`. You have a few choices: you could use a mock, you could use an `ExecutorService` that [runs with the current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581188/is-there-an-executorservice-that-uses-the-current-thread), or you could inject a standard `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, then call `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()` in your test.

You could also return a `CompletionStage<Void>` from `getCouponAndNotifyAsync()` that you can wait on in the test.

Comment: whatever written before assertTrue in my test case is it fine?

Comment: Updated the test cases in question, but still its not working

Answer (score 2):

To verify your asynchronous method is called, you can use

```
 verify(<<your service>>, **timeout(100)**.times(1))
      .<<your method>>(<< arguments>>);
```

ex:-

```
verify(service, **timeout(100)**.times(1))
      .getCouponAndNotify(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), any(NotificationRequest.class));
```

Refer https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/verification/VerificationWithTimeout.html

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have this code:

```
public void method() {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            //logic
            //logic
            //logic
            //logic
        });
    }
```

Try to refactor it to something like this:

```
public void refactoredMethod() {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::subMethod);
}

private void subMethod() {
    //logic
    //logic
    //logic
    //logic
}
```

After that, test the subMethod this way:

```
org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(classInstance, "subMethod"); 
Mockito.verify(...)
```

This isn't a perfect solution, but it tests all the logic inside your async execution.