# How to test with mockito a method that is running an async thread

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, completable-future, junit-jupiter

I have the following code which I want to test:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class DispatcherTask {

    private final MyClassService myClassService;
    private final SreamingService streamingService;
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private final Set < String > dispatching = new ConcurrentSkipListSet < > ();
    private final RetryPolicy < Object > httpRetryPolicy;

    public DispatcherTask(MyClassService myClassService, SreamingService streamingService) {
        this.myClassService = myClassService;
        this.streamingService = streamingService;
        this.httpRetryPolicy = new RetryPolicy < > ()
            .handle(HttpClientErrorException.class)
            .onRetriesExceeded(e - > log.warn("Max retries have been exceeded for http exception"))
            .withBackoff(2, 3, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
            .withMaxRetries(5);
    }

    public void initMethod(MyClass myclass) {
        Failsafe.with(httpRetryPolicy).with(executor)
            .onFailure((e) - > {
                // TODO log.error();
                myClassService.updateStatus(myclass.getId(), Status.FAILED);
            })
            .onSuccess((o) - > {
                MyClass updatedMyClass = myClassService.updateStatus(myclass.getId(), GameStatus.ENDED);
                streamingService.storeData(updateMyClass);
                dispatching.remove(myclass.getPlatformId());
                //TODO log.info()
            })
            .runAsync(() - > {
                MyClass updatedMyClass =
                myClassService.updateStatus(myclass.getId(), Status.STREAMING);
                streamingService.polling(StreamedClass.builder().myclass(updatedMyClass).build());
                // TODO log.info()
            });
    }
}
```

This is my JUnit test with `Mockito`:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class DispatcherTaskTest {

    @Mock private MyClassService myClassService;
    @Mock private StreamingService streamingService;
    @InjectMocks private DispatcherTask dispatcherTask;

    @Test
    void test() throws InterruptedException {
        //given
        MyClass myclass = new MyClass().setId(1L).setName("name").setStatus(Status.CREATED);
        when(myClassService.updateStatus(myclass.getId(), Status.STREAMING)).thenReturn(myclass);
        when(myClassService.updateStatus(myclass.getId(), Status.ENDED)).thenReturn(myclass);
        doNothing().when(streamingService).polling(any());
        doNothing().when(streamingService).storeData(any());
        //when
        dispatcherTask.initMethod(myclass)
        //then
        verify(myClassService, times(1)).updateStatus(myclass.getId(), Status.STREAMING);
        verify(myClassService, times(1)).updateStatus(myclass.getId(), Status.ENDED);
    }
}
```

If I run it like that the last verify that checks the status `ENDED` fails. If I add a `Thread.sleep(3l);` it passes. Is there a better or more secure way to pass the test without adding the `sleep()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going to be difficult to test the policies of `Failsafe`, for example: how will you emulate a test that says : "I will retry 3 times and on the 4-th one I will succeed.", because you do have that `withMaxRetries(5)`. For that I would suggest you read what `thenAnswer` in `Mockito` does, instead of `thenReturn`. At least this is how we test our code that uses `Failsafe`.

To you question though, just use `dependency injection` (which people think is only present in `Spring`). So re-write your code to:

```
 public DispatcherTask(MyClassService myClassService, StreamingService streamingService, ExecutorService executor ) {
```

notice that your `ExecutorService` is now passed in the constructor. And now create a real instance of `DispatcherTask`, with all it's dependencies mocked:

```
 DispatcherTask dt = new DispatcherTask(
       myClassService,       // this one is a Mock
       streamingService,     // this one is a Mock
       someExecutorService   // and what is this?
 );
```

what is `someExecutorService`? Well it is an `ExecutorService` that will execute your code in the same thread that runs the unit test. Choose any  [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581188/is-there-an-executorservice-that-uses-the-current-thread), as an example. Remember that `ExecutorService` is an `interface`, so creating an implementation that runs in the same thread is trivial, like [this answer did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13726463/1059372).

Answer (score 2):

Two alternatives that may work

***1 - Add `shutdown` and `await` methods in the Dispatcher***

You could add the `shutdown` and  `awaitTermination` methods in your Dispatcher Class. (You could unify them if wanted)

```
public class DispatcherTask 
{    
  //...
  public void shutdownExecutor()
  {
     executor.shutdown();
  }
  public void waitToFinish(long seconds)
  {
     executor.awaitTermination(seconds,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
  //...
}
```

> **[`boolean awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))**
>
> *Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown
> request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted,
> whichever happens first.*

---

With this method in your Dispatcher, the test could be altered so you can:

```
@Test
void test() throws InterruptedException {
    //...
    dispatcherTask.initMethod(myclass);
    verify(myClassService, times(1)).updateStatus(myclass.getId(), Status.STREAMING);
   
    dispatcherTask.shutdownExecutor();
    dispatcherTask.waitToFinish(3L); //this will block without manually sleeping
    verify(myClassService, times(1)).updateStatus(myclass.getId(), Status.ENDED);
}
```

---

***2 - Add a `getExecutor` method and call `shutdown/await` in the tests***

```
public class DispatcherTask 
{    
  //...
  public ExecutorService getExecutor()
  {
     return executor;
  }
  //...
}
```

And in your test:

```
@Test
void test() throws InterruptedException {
    //...
     dispatcherTask.initMethod(myclass);
     verify(myClassService, times(1)).updateStatus(myclass.getId(), Status.STREAMING);
    
     //create a variable in the test or just invoke getExecutor
     dispatcherTask.getExecutor().shutdown();
     dispatcherTask.getExecutor().awaitTermination(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
     verify(myClassService, times(1)).updateStatus(myclass.getId(), Status.ENDED);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but is it good practice to write code that you need only for unit tests?

Comment: Take the shutdown and await method as natural methods of that class, as you may need em in many use cases. Do not think of them as just for test, but Dispatcher's root functions instead . As an alternative, you could just define a `getExecutor()` method on the Dispatcher, and invoke the shutdown and await from your tests instead

Comment: If you like the solution you should upvoted as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't even try to manage other threads in a unit test. I'm not sure where `executor` comes from in your example but I would inject a version in your test that executes on the current thread. Guava returns one from com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors::directExecutor.

Comment: I've updated the question so it is visible where the executor comes from. I'm not sure how I could use the `directExecutor` is this case